# How to capture the keyCode from a styled component?

Tags: styled-components

I am using the `styled-components` npm package and have set an event on a component like so:

```
<MyStyledComponent onKeyPress={e => doSomething(e)} >
```

How do I capture the keycode?

Answer (score 0):

styled-components do not mutate the React synthetic events object in any way, so you need to check `event.charCode` as well as `event.keyCode`.